# How to disabled hover in v-select in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

In this situation, I need help with vuetify`s styles
Can someone clarify how I can change the style of lists inside in select?
for now, highlighted whole block with an available list
Basically, I m need to highlight only one option from this list
If someone knows how to change this styles I'm were very grateful
This is my code

```
    <v-select
         ref="hoverSelect"
         v-model="productData.filters"
         :items="filterGroup"
         :rules="fieldRules"
         item-text="name"
         item-value="id"
         chips
         label="Filters"
         multiple
         solo
         class="hoverSelect"
    >
```

```
    <template v-slot:item="{item, index}">
        <v-list tile subheader style="width: 100%" >
            <v-list-item >
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-subheader>{{item.name}}</v-subheader>
                </v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-action-text>Кол-во фильтров: {{item.filters_count}} шт</v-list-item-action-text>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-divider class="ma-0"></v-divider>
            <v-list-item-group multiple v-for="filter in item.filters" :key="filter.id" >
                <v-list-item>
                    <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
                        <v-list-item-action>
                            <v-checkbox :input-value="active"></v-checkbox>
                        </v-list-item-action>
                        <v-list-item-content>
                            <v-list-item-title>{{ filter.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item-content>
                    </template>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
            <v-divider class="ma-0"></v-divider>
        </v-list>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: This is current
https://prnt.sc/xt5ptf
this is what i want
https://prnt.sc/xt5ozm

Comment: Do you have a custom theme applied? I can't reproduce the different dropdown background colors you have in the Vuetify demo in dark mode.

Comment: No its just default dark theme of vuetify

Comment: If you go to [the Vuetify demo page for the `v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#examples), switch to dark mode, you'll notice that the background of the open dropdown does not lighten like it does in your screenshot. Why is that?

Comment: As i remmember i founded this method if official documentation
https://prnt.sc/xt8cfs